# Rule clarification for Enlightened badge (again, I know)

Tags: support, badges, accepted-answer, enlightened-badge

I know that this very question was asked before (more than once), but the answers don't apply here.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879219/f-is-a-real-valued-function-f-is-differentiable-at-a-point-does-that-imply/2879221#2879221) was the first and only one given, was accepted with 10 votes, but didn't result in the badge being awarded.

The only reason I can see is that the answer needs to be accepted *after* it gets 10 votes. Is that so?

Comment: I can think of no reason why wouldn't have received that badge. It at least seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @JasonBassford I got the badge in the end. According to the timelines, nearly 4 hours after the last vote. I knew that some badges have a delay, but I thought this one didn't.

Comment: [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for) explains the criteria for earning the badge. The Enlightened badge is described in the second answer, and possible reasons for not earning a badge despite meeting its criteria are explained in the last answer.